# How to move videos from iPhone to Windows PC by cable?

Tags: iphone, video

How to move videos from iPhone?

I took long video and filled my memory. Now I wish to move it from iPhone.

If I connect it to general Windows computer, it appears as a device in My Computer. Inside it, I see `Internal Storage` folder and then `DCIM` folder.

Unfortunately, I don't see videos there. Probably they appear as some unnamed unindentified icons (see one above `IMG_2633.JPG`):

[image]

I can't drag and drop such icons.

Additionally, I can drag drop photos, but if I select to 'Move` them, they are still copied, i.e. not deleted from iPhone. If I would able to move video, it probably won't deleted too, while I need to MOVE video from iPhone.

How to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

Here is the video in app. How to know it's name and path?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Movies *should* come up in the same folder. If you cannot see the video then there are a few things to check:

- Was the video taken with a different app, and not the native camera app? If so, that data could be accessible through app data in iTunes
- Are there other folders inside the DCIM folder? After you take several photos and videos, they get spread into multiple folders.
- If you enable photo syncing in iTunes can you then see the files you want, even if this is just a temporary measure to test it's there?

The "device" type icon you see can be ignored. You won't be able to copy or delete it, and usually after you disconnect and reconnect your phone they will disappear, particularly if you've deleted the rest of the photos.

Cutting/pasting doesn't always seem to delete them on the device, but if you are sure you've backed up all the photos you can just highlight them and delete them all.

Comment: Videos were taken with the same standard app, same as photos. How to check which folded they are in, having iPhone at hand?

Comment: Using iTunes has additional problems: each time I connect phone to laptop, it says it is no longer in pair with this computer and begins very long process which I try to avoid to.

Comment: I suggest following these steps https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204095 to make sure the connection is properly working

Comment: All these voodoo actions already done of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what iOS version you're using. I tested on iOS 12 and Win7 with iTunes installed. Just plug the iPhone with a normal USB type-a to lightning cable, then type the password to trust the computer on my phone.

The iPhone appears as a portable device in My Computer and  a similar path Internal Storage - DCIM - 100APPLE I can find the videos. Simply right click then `cut and paste` can complete the move operation. Drag can't do it, it's considered `copy and paste`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It might be other way to do it, but I would upload it to dropbox from the iPhone (with Dropbox.app) and then delete it from iPhone once checked it uploaded properly.